# Multiple Cells Not Updating into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Fairly new to php, please forgive me if my code is not eloquent.

I have a table/form with multiple rows/cells. Each cell is a drop down box. I've built this to UPDATE existing mysql-rows.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to press the submit button on the form and UPDATE all the mysql-rows. I've successfully updated mysql fields individually, but this is my first time trying to update multiple sql-rows at the same time.

In my front-end (let me know if you need me to post it), I run the below code to create a new increment variable for each -input type="submit" name="blah"...-

```
$namefieldname = 'name'.$i;
$positionfieldname = 'position'.$i;
$hoursdropdown = 'hours'.$i;
$overtimedropdown = 'overtime'.$i;
```

So name="blah" I write as name="'.$namefieldname.'"  for example. I have a different form that uses this same $i concept to INSERT information and it works fine.

Below is the code that I'm not getting to work. This is what the -form action- goes to. The page processes without errors - but doesn't update mysql. I've double checked all names and everything is spelled correctly.

For now I've cut down the columns to try to get just this one column to update mysql.

```
<?php

include_once('toolbox.php');
   //mysql connect info

$projectid = $_POST['projectid'];
$transcriberid = $_POST['transcriberid'];
for($i=0; $i<$staffcount; $i++) {
   $positionfieldname = 'position'.$i;
        //is a drop down of 5 choices

$thisposition = $_POST[$positionfieldname];

mysql_query("UPDATE transcribers SET transcriber_position='$thisposition' WHERE transcriber_id= '$transcriberid'");
}

header('Location: ./);


?>
```

Comment: where is your query for multiple columns?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: tadman - thank you so much for the input and guidance. I really appreciate the time and the links you sent. I'll start researching and learning PDO as you mention. Thanks again for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use the `mysql` extension in new programs any more, because it is deprecated since version 5.5, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, use `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension.

Second, it is important to handle user given data (e.g. from `$_POST`) appropriately before using them to concatenate sql statements. If the user gives a quote sign, he/she could alter your statement such as terminating it and update some other data in some other tables. If you use PDO_MySQL, function [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) can help you to prevent this:

```
$thisposition = $mysql_connection->quote($_POST[$positionfieldname]);
```

Even better is to use a prepared statement. It contains only placeholders where user provided data is used and the actual data is bound to this placeholders.

```
$stmt = $mysql_connection->prepare("UPDATE transcribers SET transcriber_position=:value");
$stmt->bindValue(':value', $transcriber_position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

For updating multiple columns in a table, you can just list them, separated with comma, here an example:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE transcribers SET transcriber_position='$thisposition', transcriber_value=5 WHERE transcriber_id= '$transcriberid'");
```

Comment: PDO can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) which is a whole lot better than manual escaping.

Comment: Hey Joachim! Thank you very much as well for your time and answer. I'm going to switch over and start learning PDO and switch everything out. I'm fairly new to all of this so I really appreciate the help and your time. Sincerely!